# Has python some notice about multi-thread?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using pycharm(2021.3.2) and python(3.10.2).

I don't know why this situation was happened. multi-thread issue???

When I attached debugger in # case 1, it worked.

```
#case 1

if cond_v[0] in line[4]:
     line[4] = line[4].replace(i, "") # debug point attached
```

But,

```
#case 2
if cond_v[0] in line[4]:
     line[4] = line[4].replace(i, "")     # debug point attached
     line[4] = line[4].replace("||","|")  # debug point attached
```

In this situation, debuger is not worked and
terminated by 1073741819 (0xC0000005).

When I erase debugger point, It is working successfully without 1073741819 (0xC0000005).
(Of course, the result has problem. So I wanted to attach debugger)

Now, I resolved bug by moving "line[4] = line[4].replace("||","|")" to other line and using debugger.

But, I want to know why this situation is happened. It's like a "Schrödingers Katze".
I'm very confused. Why was this occurred?

Answer (score 0):

It must be a debugger bug.  C0000005 is what WIndows calls "general protection fault" and what Unix calls "segmentation fault" -- the use of an invalid pointer.  You could try filing a bug against PyCharm, but unless you can come up with a reasonably small test case to reproduce it, there's not much they can do.

Comment: Ah Thanks for your advice. I thought there were some multi processing issue. Have a nice day!